# Using a parameter in a DataTable - ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, oracle, datatable, tableadapter

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2010
- Windows Forms Application
- Oracle Database

I am trying to use a parameter in a DataSet.xsd DataTable.
The query and parameter work fine in Query Builder but gives an error if I try "Preview Data" or use in my application.

> Error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

For full details on the application setup / my troubleshooting so far see here:
http://www.fullstackbusinessdesign.com/forums/ORA-01008.html

Comment: Could you post the table definition and SQL expression?

Comment: @MarkRobinson: see the link that Baxter ends his question with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the OleDb provider for Oracle. 
The bind variable should be a question mark ? not :DEPTCODE

The bind variable :DEPTCODE would be valid for System.Data.OracleClient.

Many thanks to Prashant Kumar for this solution.
http://forums.asp.net/members/Prashant%20Kumar.aspx